# EF6 SQL Server configuration without App.config (net461 / aspNetCore app)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm converting a working ASP.Net MVC website to an ASP.NET Core website. I'm trying to make the application work without App/Web.config (as seems to be the default for aspnetcore apps) but my EntityFramework connection to SQL Server is broken. After quite some time I get the following error:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)

Because I have no App.config / Web.config in the ASP.Net Core website I'm using a `DbConfiguration` class to tell EF to use SQL Server:

```
public class SupportManagerDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SupportManagerDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderServices(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, SqlProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(SupportManagerDbConfiguration))]
public class SupportManagerContext : DbContext
{

    public SupportManagerContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SupportManagerContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity
{
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var db = new SupportManagerContext("Server=(local);Database=SupportManager;Integrated Security=true");
        var user = db.Users.First();
        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This works fine in the 'old' ASP.Net website as long as I keep the ConnectionString in the Web.config (which of course includes the providerName as well), even with the DbConfiguration class added and the EntityFramework section removed from the old website's Web.config. When I remove the ConnectionString the same thing happens in the old website.

So basically it probably boils down to the providerName that's missing, but I'm having a hard time finding anything specific to this problem.

Comment: Does this code represent a minimal example of the problem and we can use that to duplicate the problem?

Comment: I can help if you show code of how you set your connectionString.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, rewrote most of the question after discovering the problem is not related to net461 at all. Added full code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, the solution was very subtle.

`SqlConnectionFactory` has a second constructor with parameter 'baseConnectionString'. If I would set that to `Server=(local);Integrated Security=True` then it would suddenly work. Documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.sqlconnectionfactory.sqlconnectionfactory(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory.) notes the following for the parameterless constructor:

> Creates a new connection factory with a default BaseConnectionString property of 'Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;'

Apparently not overriding the `baseConnectionString` is somehow preventing this from working as I would have expected. However, this still differs from configuration as I would've done it through Web/App.config.

In the old project's Web.config the `DefaultConnectionFactory` was set to `LocalDbConnectionFactory`. This seems really awkward since I'm trying to use an actual SQL server database, but it has always worked when used in Web.config. As such, changing the `DbConfiguration` class as follows provides the same configuration through code:

```
public class SupportManagerDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SupportManagerDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("mssqllocaldb"));
        SetProviderServices(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, SqlProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}
```

And finally, I'm somewhat satisfied with the solution since it at least mimics the old situation, even though it's still not as easy as I'd expected.